# Find a formula for the inverse of the function. $f(x) = \frac{4x − 1}{2x + 3}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Please tell me know if my answer is right and whether the steps are correct? Thanks.

$f(x) = \frac{4x − 1}{2x + 3}$

Step 1: Write $y=f(x)$

$y=\frac{4x-1}{2x+3}$

Step 2: Solve this equation for $x$ in terms of $y$ (if possible)

2(a) Multiply both sides by $2x+3$

$(2x+3)\cdot(y)\ =\frac{4x-1}{2x+3}\cdot(2x+3)$

2(b) Distribute y term

$2xy+3y = 4x-1$

2(c) Isolate  $x$ and $y$ terms

$2xy + 3y = 4x - 1 $

$-2xy+1 = -2xy$

$3y+1 = 4x-2xy$

$3y+1 = x (4-2y)$

2(d) Divide both sides by $(4-2y)$

$x=\frac{3y+1}{4-2y}$

$f^{-1}=\frac{3x+1}{4-2x} $

Comment: $f^{-1}(y)=\frac{3y+1}{4-2y}$ then $f^{-1}(\frac {4x-1}{2x+3})=\frac{10x}{10}=x$. Thus, you are right!

Comment: You may also notice that, assuming $ad-bc\in\{-1,+1\}$, there is an isomorphism between the space of functions $\displaystyle\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ under composition and the space of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ with determinant $\pm 1$ under multiplication, so to find the inverse function of $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is essentially the same as finding the inverse matrix of $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$, that by Cramer's rule is a multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - Ben is obviously just learning about function inverses. I can assure you he is not going to notice isomorphisms on a space of functions! !-)

Comment: @PaulSinclair But such comments could be insightful for the rest of us :). Remember the point of this site is not just to answer questions for the people who ask!

Comment: @PaulSinclair I liked Jack's comment and agree with Peter. In fact I wanted to post in something similar. This question comes up every now and then. Something new for those who teach is also not entirely out of scope of the site hopefully..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\dfrac{4x-1}{2x+3}$

swap $ x,y $

$x=\dfrac{4y-1}{2y+3}$

Solve back $y$ in terms of $x$

$y=\dfrac{3x+1}{-2x+4}, $  done.

EDIT1:

It is an interesting *bi-linear* or *fractional linear* function.  Notice that coefficients in the left diagonal got swapped and signs of right diagonal elements changed,

$$ \dfrac{a x + b }{c x + d} \rightarrow \dfrac{d x - b }{-c x + a} $$

leaving $ (a d - b c) $ unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is correct and your result is correct. You could however stand to delete the line $-2xy+1=-2xy$ from the proof. I get that you were demonstrating what you did to both sides, but it doesn't make sense with the equals sign, and it's possible to go directly from $2xy+3y=4x-1$ to $3y+1=4x-2xy$ anyway.

You can always double check you are correct by plugging in a few value of $x$ and $y$. For example, we can try $x=0$ in the first equation, which gives $y=-\frac{1}{3}$, and plugging in $x=-\frac13$ into the $f^{-1}$ equation gives you $0$ as desired.